# Rspec truncating schema_migration table when performing a custom SQL "ALTER TABLE" statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

When running this SQL:

```
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE enrollments ALTER role TYPE roles USING role::roles;
    SQL
  end
```

And performing a `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`, the table `schema_migrations` get truncated:

```
select * from schema_migrations ;

 version
---------
(0 rows)
```

Why?

Comment: Are you using still using `schema.rb` instead of SQL dumps by any chance?

Comment: Hi @max, thanks for answering! Not sure what you mean though. I've created two migrations. Running only the first one (creating enums), works fine. Migrating the seconde one (above example), empties the `schema_migrations` table.

Comment: Rails allows you to dump the schema as ruby or SQL. The former is better at cross platform for different databases but it can't deal with database specific features like native enum types. https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/01/15/the-pros-and-cons-of-using-structure-sql-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html

Comment: Wow, I feel like I've been living under a stone for years... The issue has been resolved. Many thanks!